# Limit Google Form submissions depending on the count of answers to a question

Tags: google-apps-script, limit, google-forms

It is my very first foray into Google Forms and Apps Script. I made a registration form which asks for the user's university (with 41 options in a dropdown menu). I am opening the registration to only 400 slots, which will be composed of 300 users from University A, and to 100 NOT from University A. I need help so I can limit the registration process to meet these parameters.

So far, I have edited the linked Spreadsheet and added 2 columns. Cell 'X1'  has a `=COUNTIF()` function returning the number of University A occurrences, while cell 'Y1' has `=(COUNTIF(range, "<>")-X1-1)`. Then I started getting these values through the following:

```
function CountUni() {
    var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(mySpreadsheet);
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(mySheetname);
    var UniArng = sheet.getRange('X1');
    var UniAtotal = UniArng.getValue();
    var nonArng = sheet.getRange('Y1');
    var nonAtotal = nonArng.getValue();

// Need code here

}
```

From what I read, I need to call this from an onFormSubmit trigger. But I need help on how to do that, as well as how to actually fulfill the registration parameters, thank you.

Comment: The code will only be effective if registrations are sequential. If two people load the form at the same time, the submission of one will not influence the submission of the other. Why? Because Google Forms do not run or execute scripts in respondent mode. In other words, you cannot perform pre-submission validation that spots remain unless you use a different form provider.

Comment: Appreciate that information, @tehhowch. I will have to do with the script running every each form submission. I will just have to inform the responder that slots are full after the fact.